# Пагинация с относительными путями в Laravel

Tags: laravel

после вызова
`$articles->links();`
из view на странице создаются ссылки вида http://site/articles/page=n. Как сделать /articles/page=n ?

Comment: Наверное, можно после `paginate()` прописать `setPath(Request::path())`

Comment: функция setPath не найдена. Нашел другое решение - ``LengthAwarePaginator::currentPathResolver(function() { });`` перед вызовом paginate